# How to convert a date into a random index in a list?

Tags: javascript, html, date, random, indexing

I need something that generates a random item from a list, but that item is randomised every day and is consistent for all users. This is on a website, and thus using JavaScript (although really I just need the algorithm you'd follow, *not necessarily* the code itself).

I've got day, month, and year stored in variables, but what could I do to convert this into an integer between 0 and list length?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple algorithm:

[Pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) 3 integers to 1:

`seed = pair(day, pair(month, year))`

use this int to seed a [random number generator](http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html), for desired randomness

`seed -> [0, 1, 2, ..., array.length - 1]`

```
index = Math.round(randomOf(seed) * (array.length - 1));
element = array[index]
```

---

Here's a basic javascript implementation of the aforementioned pairing function:

```
function pair(x, y) { return ((x + y) * (x + y + 1)) / 2 + y; }
```

---

implementing randomOf (check the link above for "random number generator"):

```
randomOf(seed){
   Math.seedrandom(seed);
   return Math.random();
}
```

Comment: Okay, woah there, that's a lot of stuff I don't understand. Is there an easy way of pairing in JS? There doesn't seem to be a Math function for it. Also, how am I making use of this seeded number generator? How do I incorporate that into my code?

Comment: So I understand and have implemented the first half - I have the seed, and using the CodePen today's date comes out as 2091584116531. It's just the second bit I don't follow, using the seeded random function that doesn't actually exist in JavaScript yet is somehow obtainable from this David Bau guy. How would I go about actually making a seeded random function work?

Comment: If I were you, I'd just use that  seed int you have, and use the modulo operator with the array length, for a quick, easy, pseudo random value

Comment: That makes sense Tobiq, that was my plan if you abandoned thread or I couldn't figure anything else out. Do you have any idea how pseudo this pseudo random value is? Is it at all noticeable compared to if I'd done it differently?

Comment: @Harry Unfortunately I have no idea. The however, unless you're using massive arrays with lengths in the millions, that seems like it should be quite random. I'll edit my answer to include info about random seeding

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom. So the idea is to change the seed for the random function to the date (maybe just the month, day, and year). For example:

```
Math.seedrandom('August 19, 1975');
console.log(Math.random());    // 0.8213442237794714
console.log(Math.random());    // 0.9082914871756658
```

and then to convert it to an integer you can use the function describe here:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

edit:

Then for example to use it to get something in an array

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

let arr = ['firsEl', 'secondEl', 'thirdEl', 'fourthEl'];
let d = new Date(); //get todays date
let month = d.getMonth();
let day = d.getDate();
let year = d.getFullYear();
//make the random with seed
Math.seedrandom(`${month} ${day}, ${year}`);
//and finally using the function for int
let item = arr[getRandomInt(0, arr.length)]; 
console.log(item);
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.4.4/seedrandom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't explain how to go from a date to a corresponding (but seemingly random) element of an array. This is just generating a series of numbers using a string date (which isn't provided) as a seed.

Comment: I added an example.